# Trouble Enabling iOS Device on Mac's Audio Midi Setup

Tags: ios, mac, audio, midi

I'm currently using a Macbook Pro 13" mid 2012(macOS Catalina 10.15.7) and an iPhone 11(iOS 14.4). I want to stream my iPhone audio to my Macbook using Mac Audio Midi Setup.

[image: screenshot]

As shown in the image above, I have the option to press `Enable`. After I press it once, I can see a new iPhone device appear on the Input device list but it quickly resets itself and disappears. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's registering properly. It should show the device name. Try rebooting everything, test with the phone fully awake & unlocked (though it should register even if not)

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, I purposely blurred out the device name for privacy reasons.